# Use encrypted Home between two Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, encryption, home-directory, 13.04

I have an encrypted "/home" partition separated from "/" partition using ubuntu12.04.
Now I want to install ubuntu13.04.Can I share that "/home" partition as ubuntu13.04's "/home" and use it for these two ubuntu?

If it's possible, I should do it during ubuntu13.04 installation?

Answer (score 0):

I really haven't tried this, but from reading several Ubuntu and Linux books, I can say:

You should be able to use a shared /home partition across Ubuntu distributions, providing that your login password is the same on both
installations.

Also, I would recommend that you move your home directory to its own partition, just in case you run out of space, or if you want to share it with another Linux distribution.

Also I would recommend using eCryptfs because, it guides you through the steps needed to create a private and secure encrypted directory.

To install eCryptfs, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils
```

Or you can download it [Here](http://ecryptfs.org/).

For information and examples that might help you accomplish this, you can click [Here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=63576) for more details.  Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I used UNetbootin app to instal Ubuntu 13.04 in usb hard disk WD company the best in my opinion.

Then restart and F2 and made the laptop boot from the usb, put the 1st chose of booting not DVD ... click on the hard drive name and alt+1 some laptop Shift+1 to never choosing the hard disk when the laptop restart ... and if you finished using usb hard disk Ubuntu 13.04 disconnected and restart.

And restart to Ubuntu 12.4

Some time you restart and F2 and F9 or F8 to load the old choice.

When you want to use usb hard disk do the same just for booting method.